# Can't find ogr2ogr on MacOS

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr

After years working with Linux and Windows I had to move to MacOS. So far I succeeded in installing QGIS from the QGIS website. But I can't find ogr2ogr - I'm pretty sure it is installed on my system.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install GDAL if it's not installed.

```
brew install gdal
```

using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you installed the application

1) If you download QGIS from [Official QGIS download](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/), [all dependencies (Python, GDAL, etc)  are bundled within the application](http://blog.qgis.org/2019/07/29/introducing-new-qgis-macos-packages/) -> `ogr2ogr` is within the application

```
/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ogr2ogr
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ogr2ogr
```

But, as indicated on the website

> Additional GDAL format plugins and PROJ grids are available at
>   [kyngchaos.com](https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/).

Here, you can download a complete GDAL Framework  that is installed in */Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/* (`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Programs/ogr2ogr`)

2) If you download from [KynChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis/), you need to install the GDAL Framework (see [QGIS install on Mac](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/qgis-install-on-mac/)) and the path is `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Programs/ogr2ogr`

3) if you use [Homebrew](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=qgis), the paths are differents